# Cant post base64 image on my post request with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64

I have a problem to send an image with my json, when receiving the body in the api, the "profile_image" attribute comes with no value, but it was suppose to come to base64's uri.

```
  function getBase64(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return reader.result;
  }

        var file = document.getElementById("imgid").files[0];
        var base64File = getBase64(file)

body = {
          profile_image: base64File,
          name: "test",
          age: 19
}

$.ajax({
            url:
              "api.com/user",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ user: body }),
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              );
            },
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `readAsDataURL` is an asynchronous method. the return statement would make the function ends up before the reader finishes the extraction.

```
var getBase64 = function (file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            base64String = reader.result;
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
}

var file = document.getElementById("imgid").files[0];
getBase64(file).then((base64String) => console.log(base64String) )
```

Comment: got the base64 url but when i post it into ajax json, the response of the api doesnt upload the file, and doesnt even shows the "profile_image" key on parameters... :/

Comment: the ```then``` method of the ```Promise``` object is also asynchronous. You need to put the post method into the fallback function in the ```then``` method. ```getBase64(file).then((base64File) => { var body = {profile_image: base64File, name: "test", age: 19}; $.ajax({xxx}); }```

Comment: dude, i really appreciate your help, honestly, you saved me alot, didnt know how to thanks, but really, very thank you <3